# How to use cl_xslt_processor to parse an XML document with namespaces?

Tags: xml, xslt, abap

I have the following `XML`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Version #1.0-->
<NominaIndividual xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                  xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
                  xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
                  xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  SchemaLocation=""
                  xsi:schemaLocation="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual NominaIndividualElectronicaXSD.xsd">

    <Devengados>
        <Anticipos>
            <Anticipo>1.00</Anticipo>
            <Anticipo>2.00</Anticipo>
            <Anticipo>3.00</Anticipo>
        </Anticipos>
    </Devengados>

    <Deducciones>
        <Anticipos>
            <Anticipo>4.00</Anticipo>
            <Anticipo>5.00</Anticipo>
            <Anticipo>6.00</Anticipo>
        </Anticipos> 
    </Deducciones> 

</NominaIndividual>
```

This `XML` is condensed into an `XSTRING`. From this `XSTRING` I would like to retrieve all nodes I want, for example `NominaIndividual/Devengados/Anticipos`.

As of now, I can successfully do it with the code below, but *ONLY* if I completely remove all the namespaces from `NominaIndividual`:

```
    DATA lo_xslt  TYPE REF TO cl_xslt_processor.
    DATA lo_nodes TYPE REF TO if_ixml_node_collection.

     CREATE OBJECT lo_xslt.

    lo_xslt->set_source_xstring( iv_xml ).

    lo_xslt->set_expression( '//Devengados/Anticipos/Anticipo').  
    lo_xslt->run( '' ).

    lo_nodes    = lo_xslt->get_nodes( ).
    ro_iterator = lo_nodes->create_iterator( ).
    ro_node     = ro_iterator->get_next( ).
```

In this code, that last object `ro_node` contains all the information I need. But the thing is: this object is only created if I completely delete all the namespaces from `NominaIndividual`:

For example, if I modify the XML to this, it works:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Version #1.0-->
<NominaIndividual>
   ...
</NominaIndividual>
```

But this, that is the original XML, doesnt:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Version #1.0-->
<NominaIndividual xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                  xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
                  xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
                  xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  SchemaLocation=""
                  xsi:schemaLocation="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual NominaIndividualElectronicaXSD.xsd">
   ...
</NominaIndividual>
```

This said, how to I navigate through this XML tree via `XPATH` maintaining the namespaces? I know that the method `cl_xslt_processor->set_expression` has an argument about namespaces, but I don`t know how to use ir correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard for parent elements like this:

```
DATA(l_xslt) = new cl_xslt_processor( ).

l_xslt->set_source_string(
` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ` &&
` <NominaIndividual xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual" ` &&
`                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ` &&
`                   xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" ` &&
...
`         </Anticipos>  ` &&
`    </Deducciones>  ` &&
` </NominaIndividual> ` ).

l_xslt->set_expression( expression = '//*[local-name()="Anticipo"]' ).
l_xslt->run( '' ).
DATA(nodes) = l_xslt->get_nodes( ).

DO nodes->get_length( ) TIMES.
  DATA(node) = nodes->get_item( sy-index - 1 ).
  WRITE node->get_value( ).
ENDDO.
```

The general rule when specifying namespaces in `set_expression()` method is via space:

```
l_xslt->set_expression(
  expression = 'sp1:a/sp2:foo'
  nsdeclarations = 'sp1 http://uri.com sp2 http://uri2.com sp3 http://uri3.com'
).
```

Finally, DO NOT use it. It's [deprecated](https://dokumen.tips/documents/abap-xml.html) (p.24), use XSLT transformations instead

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To work with namespaces, the method `SET_EXPRESSION` has the parameter `nsdeclarations` that you use to map the namespace prefixes used in the parameter `expression` to the actual namespace URIs. I extended the answer by adding an additional namespace `demonstration:URI` for `Devengados` to demonstrate how to indicate several namespaces. Note that, as per the XML standards, the namespace prefix can be anything, what is important is the namespace URI.

```
  DATA(iv_xml) =
  ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> ` &&
  ` <NominaIndividual xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual" ` &&
  `                   xmlns:demo="demonstration:URI" ` &&
  `                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ` &&
  `                   xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">` &&
  `    <demo:Devengados>` &&
  `        <Anticipos>` &&
  `            <Anticipo>1.00</Anticipo>` &&
  `            <Anticipo>2.00</Anticipo>` &&
  `            <Anticipo>3.00</Anticipo>` &&
  `        </Anticipos>` &&
  `    </demo:Devengados>` &&
  ` </NominaIndividual> `.

  DATA(xml_utf8) = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( iv_xml ).

  DATA lo_xslt  TYPE REF TO cl_xslt_processor.
  DATA lo_nodes TYPE REF TO if_ixml_node_collection.

  CREATE OBJECT lo_xslt.

  lo_xslt->set_source_xstring( xml_utf8 ).

  lo_xslt->set_expression(
              expression     = `//pp:Devengados/dd:Anticipos/dd:Anticipo`
              nsdeclarations = `pp demonstration:URI `
                            && `dd dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual` ).
  lo_xslt->run( '' ).

  lo_nodes = lo_xslt->get_nodes( ).
  DO lo_nodes->get_length( ) TIMES.
    WRITE / lo_nodes->get_item( sy-index - 1 )->get_value( ).
  ENDDO.
```

will print:

```
1.00
2.00
3.00
```